SQL Server Audit Specs: Why does Audit Action Group DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP logs no changes?
I have a working configured audit log on my SQL Server but now I recognized that the DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP does not log changes on database permission level.
In my audit specification I added DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP. I connected it to my working audit. Then I granted a permission like:
USE [TESTDB];

GRANT SELECT ON TestTable TO TestUser;

No errors on that. I checked permissions and TestUser has that permission, but previously not. But no log entry in my audit log?
I have no problems with SERVER_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP. Permission changes on server level are logged as expected.
Does anyone have any hints? Did I missunderstood DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP? From my understanding this should log permission changes for databases.

Read the docs perhaps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver16 i suspect you want: DATABASE_OBJECT_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP

Or, perhaps it'll be SCHEMA_OBJECT_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP. The difference as I read it being that DATABASE_OBJECT_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP tracks changes to object that don't belong to a schema (e.g. assemblies, schemas themselves) whereas SCHEMA_OBJECT_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP tracks changes to objects that do belong to a schema.

Thanks Ben Thul. That was the solution. I didnt know that for all schema objects I have to use that audit group.
